# How to take variation of specific Lagrangian

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, physics

I was playing around, and I got stuck trying to take the variation with respect to a given Lagrangian.

$L =(1/2)\partial_{u}\theta\cdot\partial^{u}\theta+(\lambda/2)(1-\theta\cdot\theta)$

where $\theta$ is an N-component vector.

We should end up with

$$0 = \partial_{u}\cdot\partial^{u}\theta+ \lambda\theta$$

Could anyone help out and explain this?

Comment: Sorry about the format, could anyone also suggest where to learn how to type questions into StackExchange Properly?

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your post?

Comment: @HR-Physics don't ask just edit it.

Comment: It didn't allow me cause the edit was more than 14 characters!

Comment: Did you mean?
 $$ L =  ∂_{u}\theta ∂^{u}\theta + \frac{\lambda}{2}(1-\theta \dot \theta)$$

Comment: I forgot a 1/2 in front of the kinetic term.  There is a dot product between the two derivatives and between the two $\theta$'s.  $\theta$ is an N-dimensional vector.  There are no time derivatives on any of the $\theta$'s.  HR-Physics, is there a way to send me the code you used to produce that equation?  I could then be a little more specific, and include work in the future.

Comment: Rightclick over the formula and select display. The code has to be enclosed between dollars signs (one or two of them in each side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagrangian:
$L =(1/2)\partial_{u}\theta\cdot\partial^{u}\theta+(\lambda/2)(1-\theta\cdot\theta)$

Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$
0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \cdot \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_u\theta)}\right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial\theta} 
= \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\partial_u\theta\right) - (-\lambda\theta) 
= \partial_u \cdot \partial_u\theta + \lambda\theta
$$

The calculation is somewhat simplified, but it's in fact not much more than this.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I found my error about a week ago, the result of something stupid.  Thanks for your response.